# Projection onto a subspace.

Tags: functional-analysis

How to show that $\operatorname{proj}_V f$ is: 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{proj}_V f = \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{proj}_{f_i}f
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
given that $V= \operatorname{span}\{f_1, f_2, \cdots, f_n\}$ is a subspace of some real Hilbert space $H$, $f \in H$, and $\{f_1, f_2, \cdots, f_n\}$ is an orthogonal set.

Comment: How are $V$ and $v$ different?

Comment: there the same thing

Comment: This is not true unless $f_1, \ldots, f_n$ are orthogonal

Comment: Ok yes they are orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

Name the right hand side, and show it acts like an orthogonal projection to $V$: if $v\in V$, then fixes it, if $v\perp V$, then sends to $0$.
To simplify, you can normalize the orthogonal set.